# making class="active" for nav menu in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, nav

I'm creating a website..When it comes to the navigation menu, I listed it and need the nav bar class to be active when that menu is clicked. It's fine to give class="active" for the list tag. But I need it to be active only when clicked. How can I achieve this .?
My list is :

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="nav" id="nav">
    <li class="active">
      <?php echo anchor("cntrl/index","Home"); ?>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_name'); ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
      <?php echo anchor("cntrl/jobs","Jobs"); ?>
    </li>
    <li>
      <?php echo anchor('cntrl/logout','Logout'); ?>
    </li>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: you can do it with javascript => onclick add your class active to the item

Comment: Alos, you can check the current slug, and mark that class/id active. your class/id name has to be named after slug in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I handle this sort of issue as follows:

set the active link (which is resided in the url when the link is clicked) into an variable in the controller function which is called by the link

```
$data['active_link'] = 'home'; # for example
```

check it in the view file (**JS**):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var active_link = "<?php echo $active_link;?>";
    $("li").removeClass('active');
    $("#"+active_link).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
<li class="<?php echo (endsWith($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'cntrl/jobs')? 'active':''); ?>">
   <?php echo anchor("cntrl/jobs","Jobs"); ?>
</li>
```

Main part of this code is

```
endsWith($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'cntrl/jobs')
```

Where **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** is your current URL. and  'cntrl/jobs' is your menu which is being checked with current URL.

Comment: It is better to create a method and use accordingly. It will not work if 'cntrl/jobs' is end of your multiple menu.